Is $x = 0$ the extremum of the function $e^{-x}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}$, $n \geq 4$
Question
Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right) e^{-x},
$$
where $n \geq 4$ is a positive integer. Which of the following statements is correct?
(A) $f$ has no local extremum
(B) For every $n, f$ has a local maximum at $x=0$
(C) $f$ has no local extremum if $n$ is odd and has a local maximum at $x=0$ when $n$ is even
(D) $f$ has no local extremum if $n$ is even and has a local maximum at $x=0$ when $n$ is odd.
Attempt
After differentiating $f(x)$ I saw that $x = 0$ is a crtical point of $f$. But I am not able to conclude whether an extrema exists there or not. I know second derivative test to conclude for the extrema, but that seems too tough to apply here. Kindly help.

Have you tried graphing it?

No, I am not allowed to use software or calculator. I am unable to draw it's graph by hand.

Note
$$
f'(x)=-\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right) e^{-x}+\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right) e^{-x}=-\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-x}. $$
Let $f'(x)=0$ and then $x=0$. So if $n$ is odd, then $f'(x)<0$ for $x>0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x<0$ and hence $f(x)$ reach the maximum at $x=0$. If $n$ is even, $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(-\infty,\infty)$ and hence $f(x)$ doesn't have minimum/maximum.
